# Написать скрипт работающий со сторонними программами

Tags: скрипт

Идея такова, есть программа печати ценников, но она принимает и печатает по одному артикулу. Необходимо реализовать скрипт, который выполняет определённую последовательность действий в сторонней программе.
Подскажите пожалуйста среду разработки.

Comment: Если программа на Windows, то можно использовать простой инструмент AutoIt - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt

Comment: Его обязательно инсталлировать в систему на которой будет выполняется скрипт? Если да, то в этом проблема.

Comment: @VasiliyKuramshin: Нет, не обязательно, можно собирать независимые исполняемые файлы (standalone executables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В завимимости от операционной системы, под которой решается задача, и типа интерфейса пользователя программы, которую вы хотите автоматизировать, у вас есть несколько вариантов.

Если это Windows и GUI, используйте **AutoIt**.
Эта система позволяет на BASIC-подобном языке описывать автоматизируемые процедуры. Она поддерживает программы с графическим интерфейсом, работает на операционных системах типа Windows от XP и до 2012 R2. Кроме собственно интерпретатора языка, в пакет входит и визуальный редактор, позволяющий начать работу с программой и новичку в программировании.

Подробнее:

- [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) (англ.) — домашний сайт проекта

Если это UNIX/Linux и консоль, используйте `expect` или `pexpect` в том случае, если программы поддерживают интерактивный консольный интерфейс. Если же интерфейс не интерактивный, а это чаще всего так и есть в консольных UNIX/Linux программах, то всю автоматизацию вы можете выполнить с помощью обычного командного интерпретатора (чаще всего `bash`).